# SSLHandshakeException - Chain chain validation failed, how to solve?

Tags: android, https, sslhandshakeexception

in my application I am trying to do a HTTPS POST request to my server.
However, I keep getting SSLHandshakeException - Chain chain validation failed, all the time. I tried to send a request using POSTMAN and I got a response from the server. What can be causing this error when I try to send the request from the application?

Here a code snippet where I try to send the post request:

```
   public static JSONObject getDataLibConfiguration(Context context) throws HttpRequestException {

    int statusCode = 0;

    JSONObject commonInformation;
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

    try {

        commonInformation = ConfigurationProcessor.getCommonInformation(context);
        if (commonInformation == null) {
            return null;
        }

        URL url = new URL(BuildConfig.SERVER_CONFIG_URL);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            LogUtils.d(TAG, "url = " + url.getPath());
        }

        connection = getHttpsConnection(url);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

        byte[] gzipped = HttpUtils.gzip(commonInformation.toString());
        cos = new CountingOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); //<-- This is where I get the exception
        cos.write(gzipped);
        cos.flush();

        statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        // More code her
 }

private static HttpsURLConnection getHttpsConnection(URL url) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            MatchDomainTrustManager myTrustManager = new MatchDomainTrustManager(url.getHost());
            TrustManager[] tms = new TrustManager[]{myTrustManager};
            sslContext.init(null, tms, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        } catch (AssertionError ex) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                LogFileUtils.e(TAG, "Exception in getHttpsConnection: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            LogUtils.e(TAG, "Exception: " + ex.toString());
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error in LogCat?

Comment: It just says: "java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem was that the certificate was expired.

Comment: but in my case, It is working on almost all devices but few are getting this error message

Comment: which certificate? how to renew?

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch The server I was sending the request to had a certificate that was expired so I had to renew it on GoDaddy.

Comment: In my case, my emulator date not updated. It was few weeks late

Comment: this was my first guess, but no, it was the wrong date time. It is odd that it happens for that reason.

Comment: In my case, the certificate was expired.

In the logcat got 'javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed' or 'Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: Certificate expired at...'

Answer (score 235):

In my case it was wrong date on the phone.

Fixing the date resolved an issue

Comment: I got the same issue with an android tv emulator. 
Updating the date and setting the right time zone solved the problem.

Comment: This was the solution for me. I just set date to "automatic" and it worked. But is there a way to make it work with "manual" date settings?

Comment: @Krishnom, should work if you manually set right time

Comment: The reason of problem on Android 12 emulator was the same. Cold boot of emulator worked for me.

Comment: 13/09/2022 - I noticed that every time I start the same emulator, its date is always set to the day before, make sure to verify this.

Comment: I also had this same issue for a number of phones and realised that the date was off on all of them. Changing it to automatic fixed the issue.

Comment: yes same issue occurred in one of my device. I was using retrofit for API calling and getting this error. After setting Date Time to auto it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 49):

If you're using an emulated device it may solve the problem if you just 'Cold Boot' it.

Sometimes the date on those things can get stuck if you let them run for some time, which results in this expired-certificate-problem.

Answer (score 33):

In my case, I fetch this issue on Android Emulator.
When I clear emulator cache has resolved the issue.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me too, thank you for posting your solution, and thanks for google for giving such an amazing waste of time error description

Answer (score 15):

In my case, the issue was with the phone date. So please check it, set to automatic.

Answer (score 14):

My date and time were correct, but I didn't have "Use Network Provided Time checked" in my system settings.

I fixed this issue by going to Settings > Date and Time > Check "Use network-provided time" and also check "Use network-provided time zone".

Then this error went away.

Comment: On a OnePlus 8, both are checked but the error occurs anyway.

Comment: solution works on android emulator

Answer (score 10):

```
public static void trustEveryone() {
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }});
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }}}, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                    context.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

or check system date of your device - I had this Exception when I tried to connect with wrong date!..

Comment: I tried release an update with such code and release was blocked by Google by security reasons.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone come across this issue pertaining to specific device, then the reason should be because of incorrect date set in the device.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this error by resetting my emulator date and time. My server is working fine just I changed the date and time of my emulator as current server time zone.

Answer (score 2):

If you use android emulator, you can wipe data and run again, it works

Comment: This worked for me, after wiping my data

Answer (score 1):

@Yash Bhardwaj in the comment on @Vadim answer said that the problem was in Glide framework. I faced the same problem: Https requests to server using Ktor framework were all successful, but when Glide tried to load image from the same server, it faced the `SSLHandshakeException`.
To solve this issue you should look here: [Solve Glide SSLHandshakeException](https://medium.com/@mustafayanik/how-to-fix-android-glide-ssl-exception-ab9b2c4dbada).

To make a deal with `@GlideModule` annotation you should import `kapt` plugin and add these dependencies into your app `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the date/ time was ok and I was still getting the exception. I restarted my device and the problem went away. Hope it helps someone if all the above fails.

Answer (score 1):

In my case **SSL was not implemented** and **`s`** was added by mistake after **`http`** in the URL.

Remove **`s`** from the URL and it worked.

https://example.com updated to http://example.com