# HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed

Tags: java, android, okhttp, webservice-client

I tried to call an API with the OkHttp client, but it does not succeed in Android. The API is working fine on iOS and Postman.

I'm getting a `SSLHandshakeException` in Android only. So, what would be the reason, and how to resolve it?

**OkHttp libs**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
```

**Http Client**

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    builder.addInterceptor(logging);
OkHttpClient client= builder.build();
```

**Log:**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:362)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1134)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1089)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:849)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:722)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:238)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:217)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:299)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:268)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
```

**Tested Devices and OS Version**

1. OnePlus 6T (Android 10)
2. Samsung s5 (Android 9)
3. Samsung A5 (android 6)
4. Android Emulator (Android 11)
5. LG Nexus (android 6)

Comment: This error type means that the device SSL stack cannot verify certificate of service. What Android version are you using and what is the service you are trying to connect to?

Comment: @DominikMurzynowski Samsung s6 (android 9) and Onplus 6T (android 10)

Comment: no @YuriSchimke already referred it

Comment: @RajasekaranM once do check your mobile device date and do check with emulator too

Comment: Check for a linked cause exception, toSSLHandshakeException should retain it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [Android Emulator "Chain Validation Failed" connecting developers machine with self-signed cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923747/android-emulator-chain-validation-failed-connecting-developers-machine-with-se) and [SSLHandshakeException - Chain chain validation failed, how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265234/sslhandshakeexception-chain-chain-validation-failed-how-to-solve)

Most likely it's wrong date on the device, an expired cert (unlikely if it's working elsewhere), or missing CA certificates on your Android device.

Without the root case it Is hard to tell what's going on.  You have probably only included half the exception trace. I believe the cause is also attached.

```
    /**
     * Wraps the given exception if it's not already a {@link SSLHandshakeException}.
     */
    static SSLHandshakeException toSSLHandshakeException(Throwable e) {
        if (e instanceof SSLHandshakeException) {
            return (SSLHandshakeException) e;
        }

        return (SSLHandshakeException) new SSLHandshakeException(e.getMessage()).initCause(e);
    }
```

Comment: I have checked 4 real devices and it's having same issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the whole exception message? Is there a cause that you cut off?