Implementing Retrofit on Android Studio
I'm implementing the Retrofit library into an Android Studio project. Then my goal is calling an external API call from my Android app. Now I implemented Retrofit in my project (using the Kotlin language) without sync/compile errors.
When I run my app from the Android Studio emulator and I call a sample API, I obtain the following error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed

I think I'm having some certificate issue, but I don't know how fix it.

Hey, try searching your answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53297674/17552167 , or else try to cold boot the emulator if you are using it. Or try to check if the API which you are calling is getting called on postman or chrome. If not then you need to fix the URL.
Also, if nothing works try to provide your code and also try to change the version of dependency version.

I searched in stackoverflow.com/a/53297674/17552167, I restarted the emulator, the API is ok because from Postman it works fine, but nothing helps...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I resolved in this way:

In my API now I use http instead of https
I created the resource file: res/xml/network_security_config.xml, with:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <network-security-config> <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"> <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.example.com</domain> </domain-config> </network-security-config>
I edited my AndroidManifest.xml:
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... </application>

Now it works!
